# Cordova App in VS2015 does not build after sdkmanager update

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

Since I got some errors in my android emulator I manually updated my Android SDK using the command line sdkmanager. It seems the "old" SDK Manager does not support updates anymore. I do not have Android Studio installed (I did not need it since VS2015 installed the platform tools, too). After the update I have to use command line tools for avdmanager and sdkmanager. The "old" AVD Manager and SDK Manager do not work anymore.

However after this update Visual Studio 2015 could not compile my Codova app. I always got the error:

```
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

Before the app was building correctly.

I did set up the ANDROID_HOME variable to the SDK path (same path as in ADT_HOME). I also tried the suggestion by [Abdul Rauf Mujahid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32658931/2381164) to manually edit the regedit.

Both actions did not help.

The ADT_HOME variable is still a valid path.

It seems that others had similar problems [Shandu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714710/cordova-6-5-0-failed-to-build-android-apps-after-updating-android-studio-to-2-3)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `android` was [removed in the last update of the tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050583/2381164). In order to resolve this issue I had to downgrade my Andoid tools and platform-tools.

I downloaded the older revisions of [sdk tools Revision 25.3.0 (March 2017)](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.0.3-windows.zip) as well as [platform tools Revision 25.0.3](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r25.0.3-windows.zip) and copied them into the relevant folders.

Now I can again compile my Cordova app

Comment: I could update the Android SDK Tools to Rev. 25.2.5 and the Android SDK Platform-tools to Rev. 26. With these revisions I can stil build the cordova app